# Stripe.js + Node: How can a user save his payment information and charge my Stripe account?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, stripe-payments, fetch

I am developing an iOS mobile app, and I am currently looking at the API Reference in Node (https://stripe.com/docs/api#intro), and can't seem to make out which are correct API requests for the following case:

**How can a user on my mobile application submit and save his payment information to my Stripe account (debit card, cc, bank information, etc.)?**

**Then after, how can the same user charge or request for money from my Stripe account? And how can I transfer the money to that particular user (Could it be simply done by dashboard)?**

Thank you in advance and will upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: Create a customer, charge the customer. https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges

Comment: @koopajah Is there something similar for transferring funds? So that the user don't have to always enter in information to get the token to make the transfer API call.

Comment: Yes it's called Stripe Connect: https://stripe.com/docs/connect